# How to map XML Wrapper with same elements and other elements

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xsd, jaxb

I have an XML schema, with an element `name`:

```
<xsd:element name="name">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="given" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="family" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I need to map this to working java class.

I have a spring boot application with JAXB XML controller, that takes:

```
<name>
  <given>First</given>
  <given>Second</given>
  <family>Lastname</family>
</name>
```

If I use the automatic schema source generation (with jaxb2-maven-plugin), I get a class:

```
            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                "given",
                "family"
            })
            public static class Name {

                @XmlElement(required = true)
                protected List<String> given = new ArrayList<>();
                @XmlElement(required = true)
                protected String family;

                public List<String> getGiven() {
                    if (given == null) {
                        given = new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    return this.given;
                }
                public void setGiven(List<String> given) {
                    this.given = given;
                }

                public String getFamily() {
                    return family;
                }

                public void setFamily(String value) {
                    this.family = value;
                }

            }
```

But the problem is, when I run the spring boot application and call it with the above XML, I get an error:

```
*....Name["given"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token*
```

I have no control over the format that the data is sent, so I unable to change the XML that is received.
I've tried many different solutions, but am completely stuck with this. Can you help?

Comment: If you have control over your xml schema then change `<xsd:element name="given" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>`

Comment: The error is self explanatory as you are trying to map `String` to `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)`

**Example**

```
@Test
public void test2() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    Name name = mapper.readValue("<name>\n" + "  <given>First</given>\n" + "  <given>Second</given>\n"
                    + "  <family>Lastname</family>\n" + "</name>", Name.class);
    System.out.println(toString(name));
}

public static class Name {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public List<String> given = new ArrayList<>();
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String family;
}

public String toString(Object obj) {
    try {
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true).writeValue(w, obj);
        return w.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
{
  "given" : [ "First", "Second" ],
  "family" : "Lastname"
}
```